# Scrollable HTML Textarea in iPhone

Tags: iphone, web, textarea

Can anyone help me out in creating a scrollable textarea which works on iPhone?
Want to do it using HTML, CSS and Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

A textarea on the iPhone is scrollable by default but requires two fingers to be scrolled.